# MySQL query and count from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I would like to get the data from one table, and count all results from other table, depending on the first table data, here is what I tried:

```
SELECT
    cars.*, (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            uploads
        WHERE
            uploads.cid = cars.customer
    ) AS `count`,
FROM
    `cars`
WHERE
    customer = 11;
```

I dont really have an idea why its not working, as I'm not a regular MySQL user/coder...

Could anyone direct me in the right direction with this one?

Comment: is it throwing any exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    c.*, COUNT(u.cid) AS count
FROM
    cars c
LEFT JOIN 
    uploads u
ON
    u.cid=c.customer
WHERE
    u.customer = 11;
GROUP BY c.cid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it by joining both tables using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.customer, COUNT(b.cid) totalCount
FROM    cars a
        LEFT JOIN uploads b
            ON a.customer = b.cid
WHERE   a.customer = 11
GROUP BY a.customer
```

using `COUNT(*)` in `LEFT JOIN` will have records to have a minimum count of 1.

Comment: This one selects only one record from the `cars` table. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  cars.*,COUNT(uploads.*) as uplloaded 
from cars 
left outer join uploads on  uploads.cid = cars.customer
where  cars.customer = 11 
group by uploads.cid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT  customer, COUNT(cid) totalCount
FROM    cars 
        INNER JOIN uploads 
            ON (customer = cid)
WHERE   customer = 11
GROUP BY customer
```